# Reply button or CTRL+R not active

Tags: pantheon-mail

Just testing a Danish install of Juno for my dad, and perhaps my self again.

I connected mail to his hotmail account.

I can compose new message and forward old mails.

The problem is, I cannot reply to any mails. Reply and reply-all buttons are 'grayed out', and CTRL+R doesn't work either?

What information can I provide you with, that will be helpful?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has already been [reported](https://github.com/elementary/mail/issues/398) to the eOS devs. However, you may want to provide your details there too.